# navbar toggler not dropping down the list

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

so i created a navbar with a toggle button using Bootstrap 4 but for some reason the button is not dropping down the list where did i go wrong.

```
<head>

<title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>

 <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

here is the code for the navbar

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a fully working output from your website in codepen.io/pen/ so that we can see the whole code output? Once we are able to reproduce the error there, we can help.. Providing only the `nav` is not enough for us to replicate your issue. Also please share what you did to try to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you integrate bootstrap properly? It will be better if you put your entire code so that anybody can check easily.

Comment: yes i did here is the link to css and bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class `navbar-expand-sm` to `navbar-expand-md` of the navbar, because of this your button was not accessible in the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```